# Realizing Facebook friends request like slider

Tags: react-native

I am developing my first React Native + Redux app. In my app I want to develop something similar to the friends requests slider of facebook:

[image]

There is a slider (left/right) where you can see the current content in a box and a little bit of the next and preview item. When swiping up or tap the content should be come to "full screen". Swiping left or right is disabled in full screen.

Only the current and maybe the two next and the two previous slides should be loaded but I think thanks to redux this is not a big deal.

Which components should I use for this?

Comment: look into react-native-swiper and go from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to approach this might be to use a library like [react-native-swiper](https://github.com/leecade/react-native-swiper) for the swiping component and then use [LayoutAnimation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/layoutanimation.html) to animate the subview into the full screen view, taking care to remove the name in the header/etc.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have another ListView where I want to show some description text on tap (item is getting higher with the text). At the moment I am calculating the new height and animate with Animated.View. This procedure would be obsolete with LayoutAnimation, or?

Comment: Yes and no. I've run into strange issues using ListView and LayoutAnimation together, specifically when reordering the ListView items. With that said, you're more than welcome to try a solution using LayoutAnimation to resize an individual list element. As far as I can remember, resizing an individual element worked fine; just make sure you check that you're not introducing any undefined behavior.